# How to upload file from resources using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I want to upload a file with selenium webdriver. The file is in resources folder of my project, how can i do ?

Comment: could u please put some code snippet?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

easy way is simple case of just finding the element and typing the absolute path of the document into it.

HTML code should look similar to this :

```
<input type="file" name="datafile">
```

Syntax:

```
//Find the element of upload button and send the path
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile"));
element.sendKeys("C:\Users\Easy\Desktop\testfile.txt");
```

Comment: i'm not using '<input>' in my HTML code '<a class="tft-btn ng-binding" ng-bind="config.messages.buttonUploadTitle" ng-click="executeUploadAction()" href="">Télécharger votre modèle</a>'